# Como criar uma View no SQL Server unificando todas as colunas de 3 tabelas?

Tags: sql, join, view, inner-join

Tenho 3 tabelas com as mesmas colunas mas com registros diferentes de períodos diferentes e sem PKs.

Gostaria de unificar elas em uma única `view` para poder analisar os dados, tem algum comando no SQL que me ajuda nisso

Sou bem novato no SQL

tentei o codigo:

```
create view vwEstudantes
select * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2012;
select * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2015_1;
select * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2015_2;
```

Comment: Pelo que pude entender o que você deseja é `UNION` e não `JOIN`. Tente: `create view vwEstudantes AS
select * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2012;
UNION ALL
select * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2015_1;
UNION ALL
select * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2015_2;`.

Comment: cara muito obrigado era isso mesmo, so precisei tirar os ; que deu certo, salvou minha noite!

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a função **UNION ALL** entre as consultas. Nesse exemplo que você passou irá utilizar duas vezes. Abçs.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(CREATE VIEW vwEstudantes AS
(SELECT * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2012
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2015_1
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.ESTUDANTES_2015_2));
```

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352569/view-over-multiple-tables-containing-same-columns)

Note que ter diferentes tabelas para apresentar os mesmos dados não costuma ser a solução ideal. A aproximação mais correta nesse caso seria haver apenas uma tabela chamada `ESTUDANTES` com um campo chamado `SEMESTRE` para diferenciá-los.